# Word for "Programmer Analyst"? (Spanish: "Analista Programador")

Tags: translation, programming, spanish

I really would like to know the correct translation of this IT role into English, because I believe that "**Programmer Analyst**" or "**Analyst Programmer**" do not make sense in English and it is a very specific role in the IT world.

In Computer Science hierarchy, from top to bottom:

1. Analyst
2. Analyst Programmer (?)
3. Senior Developer
4. Junior Developer

When you are Analyst/Programmer in Spain it means that you have some expertise and that you are given some analysis and software engineering tasks, while you still program or develop like a regular developer.

When you become an Analyst, you only coordinate the dev team and seldomly or never type a line of code again.

That should help to understand the concept I am trying to isolate. I have also heard terms like "*Software Gardener*" but they do not sound convincing either.

Comment: *Analytical programmer* or *program analyst* both make sense, not that I know specifically about this job.

Comment: Translation questions need a description of the original term. What does an *analista programador* actually do? The term *analyst programmer* certainly does exist in English — I've been one! — but without a description of your term, it's not really possible to see if what might be an equivalent English term actually is. (I'd also take exception to your putting "analyst" above "analyst programmer," but perhaps that's just me.)

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey both are grammatically correct but do not belong to the engineering world, an "analytical programmer" would be a quality, whereas "program analyst" implies that you analyze the program, which is something you don't do if you are an "Analyst/Programmer". Why the down votes?? I think the question is pretty clear! :(

Comment: @AndrewLeach you are right, I just provided a description.

Comment: Are you someone who programs analysts?  Someone who analyzes programs?  Someone who programs and analyzes something else?

Comment: @GEdgar someone who programs and analyses what others have to program as well, so to speak.

Comment: What's wrong with [programmer analyst](http://hiring.monster.com/hr/hr-best-practices/recruiting-hiring-advice/job-descriptions/programmer-analyst-job-description.aspx)?  I see the term quite often in help-wanted ads.

Comment: Given the range of differences that can come with titles in the tech world, this post on the programmers site may be useful: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/140569/238858

Comment: Assuming that the the French term "analyste programmeur" has the same meaning than the Spanish "Analista Programador", it refers to a qualification higher than a simple computer programmer and lower than a software engineer. I would then choose "Software Developer".

Comment: @Graffito for me Software Developer and Computer Programmer are equivalent, we are talking about something higher here

Comment: @Kuytel - the term "Analysta" is misleading: "analyste programmeur" (and probably "Analista Programador") corresponds to two or three years of post-secondary education.

Answer (score 0):

Software developer/ software engineer depending on whether you only code or perform other tasks from the SDLC